# UIPickerView Runtime Error Unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uipickerview, uipopovercontroller

I am trying to put a UIPickerView inside of a Popover view in the navigation bar of my application. When I tap the button that will open the popover I get the following error:

```
-[PopoverView pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75577f0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PopoverView pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75577f0'
```

This is what I have in my .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PopoverView : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerView;
    NSMutableArray *pickerArray;
}

@end
```

This is what I have for my .m file:

```
#import "PopoverView.h"

@interface PopoverView ()

@end

@implementation PopoverView

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

  // initalizes and allocates the array that holds the values for the picker
  pickerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  //adds the values to the array
  [pickerArray addObject:@"Blue"];
  [pickerArray addObject:@"Green"];
  [pickerArray addObject:@"Orange"];
  [pickerArray addObject:@"Pink"];
  [pickerArray addObject:@"Purple"];
  [pickerArray addObject:@"Red"];

  [pickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(NSInteger)component {

  return 1;

}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)picker numberofRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{

  return [pickerArray count];

}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)picker titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{

  return [pickerArray objectAtIndex:row];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Would this be caused by the fact that I am trying to create the picker and array within my PopoverView class instead of the class that contains the code for the button action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your

```
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)picker numberofRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)componen
                                            HERE ---^
```

method. It should be `numberOfRowsInComponent` with a capital "O".

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed that haha. That fixed the issue! Thank you!

Comment: Ahah I tried to find the typo, you've been faster ;). And Rygarth, you should make `PopoverView` implement `UIPopoverControllerDelegate` explicitly : `@interface PopoverView : UIViewController <UIPopoverControllerDelegate>`.

Comment: Ok I will add that too. Thanks GuillaumeA

Comment: @GuillaumeA: Sorry :-) - And shouldn't it be `<UIPickerViewDataSource>` in this case?

Comment: You are absolutely right.